# Character segmentation not working for 3,8

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to image processing. I want to perform character segmentation in OCR. I have already done necessary pre-processing. When I perform character segmentation by finding contouring it works well except for the character 3, 8.

After pre processed image looks like this,

[image: pre processed image]

Output after finding contouring for 3 and 8 is

[image]

[image]

Code used:

```
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
ret, imgThresh = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 127, 255, 0)
image, contours , _ = cv2.findContours(imgThresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

But it gives good result for other characters:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your image does not involve any complex background I used Otsu's method to pick the right threshold for me:

```
threshold, thresh_img = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

[image]

Now when you find contours it will be easier. That is because contours are found for objects or charaters that are in white.

[image]

Have a look at those characters that caused problems now:

[image]

[image]